# Is it possible to stop Sitecore from performing a publish operation?

Tags: c#, sitecore, publishing

If I click "publish" on my entire content tree in the Sitecore Desktop, I will get the dialogue telling me how many items have been processed. Sometimes I know that this operation is going to take an extremely long time (e.g. an hour). There's no way to stop this process. Of course I can close the dialogue and continue using Sitecore, but the publish is still ongoing in the background. I cannot publish anything else until it has completed.

Recycling the app pool will kill the publish, but it is very disruptive to users working within Sitecore.

**Is it possible to programatically, or otherwise, kill a publish operation without recycling the app pool?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Advanced Publish Dialog](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_Publish_Dialog.aspx) module, it has the additional functionality you require. There is a video describing the features on the [developers blog](http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.ca/2011/09/advanced-publish-dialog.html).

Comment: Now this looks like what I'm after - I'll definitely take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Recycle the application pool for the CMS on the server hosting the CMS.

This will kill the publish in the middle of whatever it was doing and force the CMS to restart.

Comment: OK, I guess that would work but it will also kick all of my content editors out and lose any work they were doing. I am after a way to do it without recycling - I'll amend the question.

Comment: AFAIK, this won't cause them to lose any work. any publishes they were trying to do will be cancelled and they'll have do a new publish.

Comment: Interesting - we tend to have difficulties when an app pool recycle occurs at the same time that they are working on content. Often, the desktop will lock up and they will begin to receive lots of errors. This usually results in them having to refresh the page or completely sign out and back in again.

Comment: you might also want to look into hooking the publish:begin event. your event handler gets passed an instance of the publisher actually doing the publish, so you may be able to cancel it through that class instance somehow... although i've never tried it.