# How can I cancel a running Sitecore Job?

Tags: sitecore

How can I cancel a running Sitecore Job?  There doesn't seem to be a method for this other than JobManager.RemoveJob(), and that doesn't seem to do anything other than remove it from the list of actively running jobs.  It doesn't seem to actively cancel anything.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Module is a bit old, and you don't state Sitecore version, but the source code could be updated to be compatible with newer version I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14690772/661447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't stop running jobs, except for resetting IIS or changing your web.config I'm afraid.

Comment: After some digging, it appears this is correct.  If you are executing a job which you control the code for, you must use some other thread signaling method to indicate your background task should stop.  What I ended up doing was just something like : while (Job.Status.State == Sitecore.Jobs.JobState.Running) { //do my job }.  The Sitecore jobs API allows you to set that value, not just read it.  Perhaps they had this in mind.